# background shape with css

Tags: css, background-color, shapes

How I can create custom background shape with css something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx6L1.jpg

```
  <div class="cover">
  </div>
```

Found this solution that is close to shape I want

```
  .cover-ugodnosti {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#202020, #202020), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49.8%, #202020 50%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50.1% 100%;
    background-position: left, right;
}
```

Comment: If you really want to draw complex shapes, use `<canvas>`, otherwise, just use an `<img />`

Comment: Agreed using a `<canvas>`, `<img>` or `<svg>` might be all options for getting the shape wanted.

Answer (score 0):

With gradient:

```css
.cover {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(32,32,32,1) 0%, rgba(32,32,32,1) 51%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 51.05%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cover"></div>
```

Or just use the image

```css
.cover {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/E4sU3IS.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I belive is not possible to add litle squares with css?

Comment: It is possible. Check out: https://projects.verou.me/css3patterns/. It's possible to put multiple backgrounds on the same element. Someone with more time on their hands could create specifically what you need here. Or you could learn how to do it yourself :)

Comment: Thank you for your help I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

skew transformation can help to get the small squares:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
body:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:200%;
  transform-origin:top;
  transform:skew(-15deg);
  background:
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) left/25% 100%,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #000 0 20px,transparent 21px 30px) bottom/100% 20px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```